# Is there a way to install civiCRM using strapi as CMS

Tags: cms-integration

I found that we cannot install CiviCRM independently, and that it requires Wordpress, Joomla, Drupal or Backdrop as CMS. Is there a way to use Strapi instead of these.

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to SE!   Short answer: no, CiviCRM requires one of those CMSes.

There is also work underway to revive a standalone version.

If you want to use Strapi (or anything else) for your front-end website then create a separate installation for Civi with a minimal configuration of one of the supported CMSes for the back-end.  You can find many other posts on here about integrating separate front-end and back-end sites.